# How to extract non int values from string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to parse this string

from this

```
"100%"
```

to this

```
[100, "%"]
```

I have no clue how to do this with javascript

Is there a regex expression for this?

Comment: More examples are needed..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can split it by [word boundaries (`\b`)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

```js
const text = "100%";

const arr = text.split(/\b/).map(e => isNaN(e) ? e : +e);

console.log(arr);
```

---

As Wyck mentioned, if your percentage has decimals, it's safer to use positive [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```js
const text = "99.9%";

const arr = text.split(/(?=%)/).map(e => isNaN(e) ? e : +e);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Beware strings with decimals like `99.9%` which would result in `[ 99, '.', 9, '%' ]`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, use a Regex

```js
console.log("100%".match(/\W|\d+/g).map(n => isNaN(n) ? n : +n))
```

Comment: You may improve the answer by breaking the regex down so that OP really understand your answer. Second the type of 100 became string instead of number